# optimisng an existing Python code

Tags: python

I wrote this code yesterday. It sorts a long data alphapetically and stock them to 26 files named from a to z. 
Every first letter goes to its proper file:
for exemple, all 'a' go to file A, all 'b' go to B file...etc.

Now, I want to optimise this code to be more python because i hade logic java in mind when i did this.

Any suggestions?

```
from os import linesep

__author__ = '1498009'
variable = []
filepath = "U:\\Mes documents\\DU\\Devoir2\\data.txt"

with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    lineList = f.readlines()
    lineList.sort()

    for line in lineList:
        for word in line.split():
            variable.append(word)

    for c in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1):
        Letter = chr(c)

    for line2 in variable:
        Letter2 = line2.split()[0][0]
        if Letter == Letter2:
            filestream = open(Letter, "a")
            filestream.write(line2 + linesep)
            filestream.close()

    print(line)
```

Comment: If you are trying to increase readability see here:   https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/     If you want others to review and comment on your working code post here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What do you mean, "more python"? (also, could you please fix your code formatting? it's very hard to read)

Comment: abaldwin99: thank you for the links.. Yes I would like you to comment my code.

Comment: Emphasis on **working code** - if this is broken (like it is as currently posted, indentation matters in Python), it's off-topic on CodeReview

Comment: oxguy3: I though that i formatted the code well.. I want to know how to format as you want it to be readable..

Comment: it is better in my python programme... it is just that i didn't know how to format code here because it put the first line in the blue square the reste of the code out of the square....etc so i played with to put them all in the blue square...hhhhh sorry though

Comment: To make it format well on Stack Overflow, paste it into your answer, then highlight it all and click the button that looks like "{ }" in the toolbar above the textbox.

Comment: oooooooooooook got it .. thank you all

Comment: i don't have enough reputaion to post ce code for comments. so can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
from string import lowercase
from os import linesep
filepath = "U:\\Mes documents\\DU\\Devoir2\\data.txt"


with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
     line_list = f.readlines()
     letters = lowercase

     # This is a technique known as list comprehension
     words = [line.split() for line in line_list]

     # This is a small trick to make a 2d list into a single list
     words = sum(words, [])

     # Sort your words into separate lists alphabeltically
     sorted_words = [filter(lambda word: word.lower()[0] == letter, words) 
                     for letter in letters]

     # Write them to files
     for letter, word_list in zip(letters, sorted_words):
         # This line removes any lists that do not have any words in them
         # You can remove it if you want all files
         if len(word_list) != 0:
             # If you wish to make the words unique, you can add this line
             # word_list = set(word_list)
             filestream = open(letter, "w")
             filestream.write(linesep.join(word_list))
             filestream.close()
```

Alright so there is quite a bit of new stuff here for you if you come from a java background.

If you wish to learn more about list comprehension: [Heres is a pretty good website](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

And if you're wondering what that 'filter' and 'lambda' words are, they are part of the magic that is functional programming. [Here is a quick introduction to python's functional programming components.](http://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php)

Finally, the 'zip' word you see simply takes two lists such as:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [5,6,7,8]
```

and transforms them into pairs based on their elements, so:

```
zip(a, b)
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]
```